# How to save another new files one by one in different name by using .csv file in C#

Tags: c#, csv

I have `.csv` file that sample of file is like this,

```
    Date,Pass,CutMark1,Marks1,CutMark2,Marks2
22/06/2017 13:04:18,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE
22/06/2017 13:04:20,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE
22/06/2017 13:04:35,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE
22/06/2017 13:04:37,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE
22/06/2017 13:04:37,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE
22/06/2017 13:04:38,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE
22/06/2017 13:04:39,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE
22/06/2017 13:04:40,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE
22/06/2017 13:04:41,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE
22/06/2017 13:04:42,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE
22/06/2017 13:04:44,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE
22/06/2017 13:04:45,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE
22/06/2017 13:04:46,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE
22/06/2017 13:04:48,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE
22/06/2017 13:04:49,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE
22/06/2017 13:04:50,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE
22/06/2017 13:04:52,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE
22/06/2017 13:04:53,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE
22/06/2017 13:04:54,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE
22/06/2017 13:04:56,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE
22/06/2017 13:04:57,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE
22/06/2017 13:04:58,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,TRUE
22/06/2017 13:05:00,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE
22/06/2017 13:05:01,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE
22/06/2017 13:05:02,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE
22/06/2017 13:05:04,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE
22/06/2017 13:05:05,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE
22/06/2017 13:05:06,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE
22/06/2017 13:05:08,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE
```

So now I want to save this file as follows;In here `Pass column` data flow is like this,FALSE>TRUE>FALSE>TRUE ..this is sample of my .csv file.but there is more raw in original file.In here I want to Separate this original .csv file like following ;

First met False so all of False details And check Marks1=TRUE then save `Discharge1_Mark1.csv`,and look at Marks2 column and if that column true then save `Discharge1_Mark2.csv`.

Secondly Pass column meet True then check Marks1=TRUE then save `Charge1_Mark1.csv`,then if  Marks2=true then save `Charge1_Mark2.csv`.

NOw again Pass column meet False then want to save file `Discharge2_Marks1.csv`.
like that I want to save my files.

I want to say in here Accordingly Pass column TRUE,False you want to save file like i mentioned before as which time that TRUE,FALSE meet.1,2,3,...you want to check respective pass column TRUE false with respective Marks1,Marks2 column.
In here I want to save my generated file respective therir columns.

If I save Marks1 then column headers should (Date,Pass,CutMarks1,Marks1 )
If i save Marks2 then column header should (Date,Pass,CutMarks2,Marks2)

Please give how I generate files as I mentioned before in my code.my code is following.

```
using System.Globalization;

  public static string dateFormatString = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";


  private void btnSeperateFile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int discharge_counter = 0;
            int charge_counter = 0;

            if (tbOutputFilePath2 != null)
            {

                List<DrawNew> ObservingData = new List<DrawNew>(); // List to store all available DrawNew objects from the CSV

                // Loops through each lines in the CSV
                foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(outputFilePath.Text).Skip(1)) // .Skip(1) is for skipping header
                {

                    string[] valuesCsvLine = line.Split(',');
                    DrawNew mngInstance = new DrawNew();

                    mngInstance.Date = DateTime.ParseExact(valuesCsvLine[0], dateFormatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture); 
                    mngInstance.Pass = (valuesCsvLine[1] == "TRUE" ? true : false);
                    mngInstance.CutMark1 = (valuesCsvLine[2] == "TRUE" ?true: false);
                    mngInstance.Marks1 = (valuesCsvLine[3] == "TRUE" ?true: false);                 
                    mngInstance.CutMark2 = (valuesCsvLine[4] == "TRUE" ? true : false);
                    mngInstance.Marks2 = (valuesCsvLine[5] == "TRUE" ?true: false);

                    ObserveData.Add(mngInstance);

                    if (mngInstance.Pass==true && mngInstance.Marks1==true)
                    {


                    }
                    if (mngInstance.Pass == false && mngInstance.Marks1 == true)
                    {

                    }
                    if (mngInstance.Pass == true && mngInstance.Marks2 == true)
                    {

                    }
                    if (mngInstance.Pass == false && mngInstance.Marks2 == true )
                    {

                    }            
                }
            }
```

This is the class for storing data of .csv file:

```
class DrawNew
    {
        public DateTime Date { get; set; } // property to store Date 
        public bool Pass { get; set; } // property to store ChargeMode
        public bool CutMark1 { get; set; } // property to store ChargeMode
        public bool Marks1 { get; set; } // property to store ScheduleStep
        public bool CutMark2 { get; set; } // property to store ChargeMode
        public bool Marks2 { get; set; } // property to store ScheduleStep 
     }
```

My problem is How I generate these files as I mentioned before.please help to solve my problem.

Comment: what content do you want to put inside the newly generated file?

Comment: @grepLines.oh sorry I edit my question now

Comment: @grepLines.Thank you sir,I added that for my question now.

Answer (score 1):

1. You will need 4 `lists` for each type of the output csv file as listed below. Depending on your if condition on each `DrawNew` object, you add that into its own list.

   - `List<DrawNew> dischargeMark1List`
   - `List<DrawNew> dischargeMark2List`
   - `List<DrawNew> charge1Mark1List`
   - `List<DrawNew>  charge1Mark2List`

     2. You create a method `GenerateOutputCsv(List<DrawNew> selectedData)` to write the data to the correct file name. You just have to do the same checking as you did in `btnSeperateFile_Click(..)` method.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote up my draft idea as below. I just focus on 4 cases:

- Pass = True, CutMark1 = True.
- Pass = True, CutMark2 = True.
- Pass = False, CutMark1 = True.
- Pass = False, CutMark2 = True.

There're maybe another cases, I think.

So, first, I create a new model to store data.

```
public class Charge
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; } 
    public bool Pass { get; set; } 
    public bool CutMark { get; set; } 
    public int Marks { get; set; } 
}
```

Then, I create 4 lists to store data for 4 cases:

```
var discharge1Mark1 = new List<Charge>();
var discharge1Mark2 = new List<Charge>();
var charge1Mark1 = new List<Charge>();
var charge1Mark2 = new List<Charge>();
```

In your for loop, I will process like below:

```
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(valuesCsvLine[0], dateFormatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            var pass = (valuesCsvLine[1] == "TRUE" ? true : false);
            var cutMark1 = (valuesCsvLine[2] == "TRUE" ? true : false);
            var marks1 = int.Parse(valuesCsvLine[3]);
            var cutMark2 = (valuesCsvLine[4] == "TRUE" ? true : false);
            var marks2 = int.Parse(valuesCsvLine[5]);
            if (pass)
            {
                if (cutMark1)
                    discharge1Mark1.Add(new Charge
                    {
                        Date = date,
                        Pass = pass,
                        Marks = marks1,
                        CutMark = cutMark1
                    });
                else
                    discharge1Mark2.Add(new Charge
                    {
                        Date = date,
                        Pass = pass,
                        Marks = marks2,
                        CutMark = cutMark2
                    });
            }else
            {
                if (cutMark1)
                    charge1Mark1.Add(new Charge
                    {
                        Date = date,
                        Pass = pass,
                        Marks = marks1,
                        CutMark = cutMark1
                    });
                else
                    charge1Mark2.Add(new Charge
                    {
                        Date = date,
                        Pass = pass,
                        Marks = marks2,
                        CutMark = cutMark2
                    });
            }
```

To programmatic create headers for CSV, you can just simply do as below:

```
private void ExportToCSV(List<Charge> data, bool discharge, int num)
{
    var filename = discharge ? "Discharge1" : "Charge1";
    filename += (num == 1) ? "_Mark1.csv" : "_Mark2.csv";
    var headerCol1 = "Date";
    var headerCol2 = "Pass";
    var headerCol3 = (num == 1) ? "CutMark1" : "CutMark2";
    var headerCol4 = (num == 1) ? "Mark1" : "Mark2";
    //your exporting function below
}
```

Hope you understand and my idea could helps.

Comment: ,Thank you for your help.I edited my content.But my problem is still not solve.I want to generate file name.one by one.In here `Pass`column want to genrate file names as I mentioned.first meet False then file name save as Discharge1,second meet True then Charge1,then meet Flse again then Discharge2,Then Charge2,like that I want to save file.save data onlt Marks1 or Marks2 is True only.getting name we want to see Paas column which mode has,TURE or False and marks1 or marks2 is only TRUE.I messed up my code.please give me a solution.if you can.thank you.

Comment: You mean, you will go through the whole data set to determine the file name it should be? Can you explain more about your "First", "Second"? Is this "First Row" then "Second Row", then so on?

Comment: In here there is a  `Pass` cplumn,pass column has TURE or FAlSE values.ok?so think pass is like charge a battery.ok?so now firstly this column we saw False data after that True after that again false and after that True,ok?then i said think like battery then if there is True then charge the batter,false then Discharge the battery.ok?like wise first meet Discharge1 then Charge1 then Again Discharge meet then file name want to correct Discharge2 then charge2 like wise check and save file.In here Marks1 think like a batter 1 Marks2 think like battery 2 then,Marks1 or Marks2 want to True only.

Comment: Now I give a example first Pass is False and Marks1=True then save file Discharge1_Marks1.csv..like wise check the marks1 and marks2 and save that files.thank you for your attention for my question.In here i want to save All False pass value which Marks1 is true.and firstly met.like wise I want to save.

Comment: Now I add example for that ,In here i added 30 raw. Pass column is False and there is Ture values in Marks1 then want to save that 5 raws with columns(Date,Pass,CutMarks1,Marks1) in Discharge1.Marks1.csv..then check marks2,in here in Pass=False there is 9&10 raws is TRue value with Marks2 then save this file in seperate with this 2 raws with column headers(Date,Pass,CutMarks2,Marks2).name Discharge1_Marks2.csv..after that this False raws Meet TRue values in Pass column but there is no Marks1 is true value between that pass =True then no need to save that file,

Comment: but there is Marks2 is true then want to save.Charge1_Marks2.csv.like wise I want to save this file.Now Pass column has False values then check marks1 and marks2 so it has TRUE also then save file like this Discharhe2_Marks1.csv and Discharhe2_marks2.csv.I think you have a idea what I want to clarify.and my original files has 60000 more raws.If you can please help me to do this.I messed up this code.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem properly, I would like to suggest like below:

In your DrawNew, I will add a new field to store the FileName which the record should be exported to which csv file.

```
public class DrawNew
{
    public DateTime Date { get; set; } // property to store Date 
    public bool Pass { get; set; } // property to store ChargeMode
    public bool CutMark1 { get; set; } // property to store ChargeMode
    public bool Marks1 { get; set; } // property to store ScheduleStep
    public bool CutMark2 { get; set; } // property to store ChargeMode
    public bool Marks2 { get; set; } // property to store ScheduleStep 
    public string FileName { get; set; }
}
```

Then, in your for loop, I use some parameter to determine the file name for each record.

```
List<DrawNew> ObservingData = new List<DrawNew>(); // List to store all available DrawNew objects from the CSV

        // Loops through each lines in the CSV
        var fileName = "";
        var previousPassValue = true;
        var count = 0;
        foreach (string line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(outputFilePath.Text).Skip(1)) // .Skip(1) is for skipping header
        {
            string[] valuesCsvLine = line.Split(',');
            DrawNew mngInstance = new DrawNew();

            mngInstance.Date = DateTime.ParseExact(valuesCsvLine[0], dateFormatString, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            mngInstance.Pass = (valuesCsvLine[1] == "TRUE" ? true : false);
            mngInstance.CutMark1 = (valuesCsvLine[2] == "TRUE" ? true : false);
            mngInstance.Marks1 = (valuesCsvLine[3] == "TRUE" ? true : false);
            mngInstance.CutMark2 = (valuesCsvLine[4] == "TRUE" ? true : false);
            mngInstance.Marks2 = (valuesCsvLine[5] == "TRUE" ? true : false);
            if (count == 0)
            {
                previousPassValue = mngInstance.Pass;
                count++;
            }

            if (previousPassValue != mngInstance.Pass)
            {
                previousPassValue = mngInstance.Pass;
                count++;
            }

            if (mngInstance.Pass == true && mngInstance.Marks1 == true)
            {
                fileName = "Charge" + count + "_Mark1.csv";

            }
            if (mngInstance.Pass == false && mngInstance.Marks1 == true)
            {
                fileName = "DisCharge" + count + "_Mark1.csv";
            }
            if (mngInstance.Pass == true && mngInstance.Marks2 == true)
            {
                fileName = "Charge" + count + "_Mark2.csv";
            }
            if (mngInstance.Pass == false && mngInstance.Marks2 == true)
            {
                fileName = "DisCharge" + count + "_Mark2.csv";
            }

            mngInstance.FileName = fileName;

            ObservingData.Add(mngInstance);
        }
```

I assume your data file is correct. And you will sort ObservingData list by FileName before exporting it to excel.

Hope this helps.

Comment: i tried this code but data are repeating that file and.not save the file as I wish.but thank your for your help in advance.

Comment: I added extra filename to store which file should a record be exported to. If you want to export it immediately, you have to update your loop instead of foreach. I've just updated here: https://pastebin.com/U4v1rceD